# Troubleshooting a failed Samba/LDAP authentication

Tags: logging, ldap, samba

This is really a more general question, but I am asking it in a specific context. How do you troubleshoot failed Samba/LDAP logins/authentications?

I am in the process of learning Samba/LDAP. I currently have a test machine on which I have Samba and openLDAP, and I created a single posix/samba user that I want to try logging onto a network share with. From my other machine running Debian, I use the Gnome "Connect to server" function to try and load the share. I enter all the relevant information, but after entering my password the prompt keeps coming back. It repeatedly asks for my password without giving me an error.

So far I have been tailing the `/var/log/syslog` file and looking at the slapd output:

```
Aug  1 11:05:16 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 fd=19 ACCEPT from IP=127.0.0.1:52280 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
Aug  1 11:05:16 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=0 BIND dn="cn=admin,dc=androcs,dc=com" method=128
Aug  1 11:05:16 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=0 BIND dn="cn=admin,dc=androcs,dc=com" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
Aug  1 11:05:16 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
Aug  1 11:05:16 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=1 SRCH base="" scope=0 deref=0 filter="(objectClass=*)"
Aug  1 11:05:16 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=1 SRCH attr=supportedControl
Aug  1 11:05:16 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
Aug  1 11:05:16 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=2 SRCH base="dc=androcs,dc=com" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(uid=tarcuri)(objectClass=sambaSamAccount))"
Aug  1 11:05:16 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=2 SRCH attr=uid uidNumber gidNumber homeDirectory sambaPwdLastSet sambaPwdCanChange sambaPwdMustChange sambaLogonTime sambaLogoffTime sambaKickoffTime cn sn displayName sambaHomeDrive sambaHomePath sambaLogonScript sambaProfilePath description sambaUserWorkstations sambaSID sambaPrimaryGroupSID sambaLMPassword sambaNTPassword sambaDomainName objectClass sambaAcctFlags sambaMungedDial sambaBadPasswordCount sambaBadPasswordTime sambaPasswordHistory modifyTimestamp sambaLogonHours modifyTimestamp uidNumber gidNumber homeDirectory loginShell gecos
Aug  1 11:05:16 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=2 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
Aug  1 11:05:16 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=3 SRCH base="sambaDomainName=ANDROCS,dc=androcs,dc=com" scope=0 deref=0 filter="(objectClass=sambaDomain)"
Aug  1 11:05:16 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=3 SRCH attr=sambaPwdHistoryLength
Aug  1 11:05:16 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=3 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
Aug  1 11:05:17 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=4 SRCH base="dc=androcs,dc=com" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=sambaGroupMapping)(gidNumber=20000))"
Aug  1 11:05:17 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=4 SRCH attr=gidNumber sambaSID sambaGroupType sambaSIDList description displayName cn objectClass
Aug  1 11:05:17 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=4 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=0 text=
Aug  1 11:05:17 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=5 SRCH base="dc=androcs,dc=com" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=sambaGroupMapping)(gidNumber=20000))"
Aug  1 11:05:17 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=5 SRCH attr=gidNumber sambaSID sambaGroupType sambaSIDList description displayName cn objectClass
Aug  1 11:05:17 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=5 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=0 text=
Aug  1 11:05:17 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=6 SRCH base="dc=androcs,dc=com" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(sambaSID=s-1-5-21-3743419441-701214183-3617868461-513)(objectClass=sambaSamAccount))"
Aug  1 11:05:17 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=6 SRCH attr=uid uidNumber gidNumber homeDirectory sambaPwdLastSet sambaPwdCanChange sambaPwdMustChange sambaLogonTime sambaLogoffTime sambaKickoffTime cn sn displayName sambaHomeDrive sambaHomePath sambaLogonScript sambaProfilePath description sambaUserWorkstations sambaSID sambaPrimaryGroupSID sambaLMPassword sambaNTPassword sambaDomainName objectClass sambaAcctFlags sambaMungedDial sambaBadPasswordCount sambaBadPasswordTime sambaPasswordHistory modifyTimestamp sambaLogonHours modifyTimestamp uidNumber gidNumber homeDirectory loginShell gecos
Aug  1 11:05:17 androserve slapd[3358]: bdb_equality_candidates: (sambaSID) not indexed
Aug  1 11:05:17 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=6 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=0 text=
Aug  1 11:05:17 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=7 SRCH base="dc=androcs,dc=com" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=sambaGroupMapping)(sambaSID=s-1-5-21-3743419441-701214183-3617868461-513))"
Aug  1 11:05:17 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=7 SRCH attr=gidNumber sambaSID sambaGroupType sambaSIDList description displayName cn objectClass
Aug  1 11:05:17 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=7 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=0 text=
Aug  1 11:05:17 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=8 SRCH base="sambaDomainName=ANDROCS,dc=androcs,dc=com" scope=0 deref=0 filter="(objectClass=sambaDomain)"
Aug  1 11:05:17 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=8 SRCH attr=sambaLockoutThreshold
Aug  1 11:05:17 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=8 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
Aug  1 11:05:17 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 fd=19 closed (connection lost)`
```

In this case it looks like it is trying to reference a `sambaGroupMapping` class, which I have not configured.

How would one usually approach this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: For starters, I would use the command line tool `smbclient` over GNOME's graphical "Connect to Server".

Comment: Yes, but I eventually need to make sure all the different methods of connecting work. Some users are going to use that feature, so I might as well try it. Although I'd agree that testing with something else makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Aug  1 11:05:16 androserve slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=2 SRCH
>   base="dc=androcs,dc=com" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(**uid=tarcuri**)(
>   objectClass=sambaSamAccount))"  Aug  1 11:05:16 androserve
>   slapd[3358]: conn=1007 op=2 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 **nentries=1**
>   text=

It means that your username was found in LDAP directory. Take a look at `audit.log` to see what happen with each step `authentication`, `accounting`, `session`, ...

Comment: OK, I am in the process of trying to get auditing enabled. I tried using the example in `man slapo-auditlog` but apparently I don't have a required module for `olcOverlayConfig` so I need to get that sorted first.